# FontAwesomeIcon "defined but never used" even though it is required

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I recently added FontAwesomeReact to my React site.  I'm using the icons in a Sidebar component that displays on every page.

Page:

```js
import React from 'react'
import Header from '../components/header'
import Sidebar from '../components/sidebar'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import Footer from '../components/footer'

class IndexPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Header />
            <Sidebar />
            <Layout>
                <p>Hello there is some content here </p>
            </Layout>
            <Footer />
        )
    }
}
```

Sidebar component:

```js
import React from 'react'
import Menucard from '../components/menucard'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faInfoCircle, /*...*/, faCheck} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
library.add(faInfoCircle,/*...*/,faCheck)

const clubAdminMenu = (
  <div>
    <h2>Club Admin</h2>
    <ul>
      <li className="pod">
        <a href="..."><FontAwesomeIcon icon="user" pull="right" /> Manage Registrations</a>
      </li>
      <li className="pod">
        <a href="..."><FontAwesomeIcon ... /> ...<a>
      </li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
)


class Sidebar extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
      <div className="Sidebar">
        <Menucard content={clubAdminMenu} />
        ...
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Sidebar
```

- At first I assumed that `<FontAwesomeIcon />` would be defined everywhere, since it's imported in `<Sidebar />` and `<Sidebar />` is on every page.  Clearly I was wrong, the icons did not show up on any page unless I explicitly included `import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'` on every single page.
- But when I include that `import` on every page, the compiler warns me that `'FontAwesomeIcon' is defined but never used` about a zillion times (once on every page that doesn't include `<FontAwesomeIcon />` in its body, even if it is included in `<Sidebar />`) I get why it's saying this, but if I remove the import, the icons do not render in the sidebar on that page.

These two things seem to contradict each other.  Am I missing something?  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You only need to imported on the files that you would need to use the `FontAwersomeIcon` keyword.

Comment: You don't have to import `FontAwesomeIcon` if you're not using it. Add the `import` statement to the file for the `Sidebar` component, and remove the `import` statement from all other files that do not use `FontAwesomeIcon`, and it should work.

Comment: show us the code of sidebar

Comment: That's what I thought too!  So why isn't that case in my project?  My `<Sidebar />` component imports `FontAwesomeIcon`, `library`, and all the individual icons, plus library.add() all the individual icons, as specified on the FontAwesome's React page.  However, the icons in the sidebar don't actually render on any page, unless I also include the `import { FontAwesomeIcon}` on that page, then the sidebar icons will render on that page.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar Updated my question

Comment: Where is the code that _uses_ `<FontAwesomeIcon>`? Importing something that you then don't actually use in your code should, and clearly is, be flagged as a useless import (because in React, you don't rely on side effects. Ideally nothing loads an asset that then becomes magically globally available. If a components needs something, it needs to import it. And then intelligent asset allocation will make sure you're not loading something more than once, but using the previously cached load)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans There are about 20 instances of `<FontAwesomeIcon />` in the `<Sidebar />` component.  Updated my answer to show it

Comment: Are you missing some syntax or is that really what it looks like? E.g. don't leave off the top level `class Sidebar extends Component` and enclosing curly brackets and the like. Skipping over irrelevant class functions and irrelevant duplicated code is fine (I edited your post so that it's less of a code wall and more to the point) but right now that Siderbar code looks all kinds of incorrect. What is it exporting? There is nothing called `Sidebar` defined, there is a const _outside_ the render function, etc. (and that const should be an instance of a component, really. Not loose jsx)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes, I skipped over some lines - Obviously it's exported as a class or else I would be getting all kinds of syntax errors or it wouldn't compile.  As stated above, my question is specifically concerning the necessity of importing `<FontAwesomeIcon />` into every single page rather than just in `<Sidebar />`, which seems like it shouldn't be necessary, but for some reason, it is.  Any thoughts on that issue?

Comment: Yeah: I agree that if your Slider imports use it, you're done. So I'd recommend first creating a [mcve] because it'll do two things: (1) demonstrate to yourself the problem with is that component, not your own case, and (2) give people here on SO, and on the issue tracker for FontAwesomeIcon, a PoC they can run to verify what you says happens, indeed happens, and have the minimum amount of code necessary to help you debug. But I'd also strongly recommend updating your code to show that class encapsulation because even if you omit lots the basic structure and var names need to work for a reader

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans After fleshing out my code a bit, I think I have created an "MCVE" comprising the single page and component listed above.  Another possible clue - The icons show as expected in my development environment running from localhost, but when I push it live I get this behavior.  Could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: of course? But that's what the dev tools are for: what does the console say, what does the network tab say, etc.If you have an MCVE, you probably want to update your post with that code, and rephrase your question in terms of that code.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Sorry - I thought what I have up there was already a "MCVE".  It's the smallest amount of code that still produces my problem.

Comment: @Henry But it can't be run. An mcve would be code that basically throws away "your" code and instead creates the bare minimum component/render chain that demonstrates the problem. There's still a lot of code that is irrelevant here, like having multiple `a` inside `li` inside `ul` inside a `div`. This code can be made much more minimal.

Answer (score 0):

This is the official documentation for Font Awesome v5.15 https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react

It says that you need to include the below code in **App.js** (Not necessarily, but if you want to use font awesome icons in a lot of files, it is a good idea to make it Global)

```
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { fab } from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";   // To use branded icons such as Google, Github, etc.
import {
    faCheckSquare,
    faCoffee,
    faInfoCircle,
    // All other icons (except fab) that you want to use MUST be declared here 
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

library.add(fab, faCheckSquare, faCoffee, faInfoCircle);    // All icons imported must be added to the library
```

And then in *every file* where you want to *use* Font Awesome icons, you must include

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
```

And then to use the Font Awesome icons, you need to do the following:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={[iconType, icon]} />
```

where iconType = 'fab', 'fas', etc.

and icon = 'github', 'coffee', etc.

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fab', 'google']} />
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas', 'coffee']} />
```

Comment: Hi BeruboIV! Yes, this is all correct. But it does not answer (or even reference) my question in any way. If you think my code violates any of this documentation, please say so and explain why. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

When you import

```
 import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
```

You need to call

```
  <FontAwesomeIcon />
```

The reason you get that message because you are just importing it but you never called it. So do as I suggested above

Comment: `<FontAwesomeIcon />` is called many times in my Sidebar component.